# How can access property of variable if difficult properties

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I access property of this type of data: Below data are into $live variable.

```
    $live =  =array:17 [▼
        "sensex" => {#1130 ▼
        +"code": "200"
        +"message": "Success"
        +"data": {#1131 ▼
            +"HIGH": "36551.86"
        }
      }
         "nifty_50" => {#1132 ▶}
         "nasdaq" => {#1134 ▶}
```

I am trying to access value of 'HIGH' property for `$live` variable in php. I have tried with below code but its give me error:

```
$live->sensex->data;
```

Error:

> Trying to get property 'sensex' of non-object

**EDITED:**

I'm trying to access this data structured data which is `$live`,

```
$data =
    {#1139 ▼
        +"chart": {#1138 ▼
            +"result": array:1 [▼
                0 => {#1135 ▼
                    +"meta": {#1129 ▶}
                    +"timestamp": array:195 [▶]
                    +"indicators": {#1137 ▼
                        +"quote": array:1 [▼
                            0 => {#1136 ▼
                                +"open": array:195 [▶]
                                +"close": array:195 [▶]
                                +"high": array:195 [▶]
                                +"volume": array:195 [▶]
                                +"low": array:195 [▶]
                           }
                       ]
                    }
                }
            ]
            +"error": null
        }
    }
```

Now **How can I access** `+"open": array:195` directly?

Comment: you're trying to access the sensex key as if it were an object property, try `$live['sense']['data']['HIGH']` and see if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It kind of looks like an associative array, then you will get the get the value by:

```
$live["sensex"] // etc.
```

Comment: why am i unable to acess with this syntax, `$live->sensex->data;` ?

Comment: In php you have Std class (using arrows `$data->key`) and associative arrays (using `$data["key"]` syntax). Depending on what datatype your data is, you need to use the proper syntax.

Comment: if i want to acess 'data' of sensex directly, what is will be right way?

Comment: oh i got it `$live["sensex"] ->data;` because its stdClass

Comment: @KINNARI `$live['sensex']->data;` looks like the way

Comment: what should I want to get out only value of `HIGH`?

Comment: $live['sensex']['data']->HIGH; ?

Comment: Looks like `$live['sensex']->data->HIGH;`

Comment: can you check again my question which is `EDITED`?

Comment: Should be something like this `$data->result[0]->meta->indicators->quote[0]->open`. The [0] is because it's an array, where you have to specify the index.

Comment: This is giving me error `Undefined property: stdClass::$result`

Comment: You're updating your post, so you see that i wrote `$data`, instead of `$live`? :) Did you try to change that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181011/discussion-between-kinnari-and-tibbelit).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Array syntax

```
$live['sensex']->data;
```

Comment: giving me error with your answer `'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'`

Comment: what should I want to get out only value of `HIGH`?

Comment: $live['sensex']->data->HIGH

Comment: can you check again my question which is `EDITED`?

Answer (score 1):

to access an `index` of an array you need to use `['particular_index_name']`.

to access a `property` of an `object` you need to use `->particular_property_name`.

in your case, `$live` is an `array`, `sensex` is an object and `data` is also an object.

so. to access the value of `HIGH`

```
$live['sensex']->data->HIGH;
```

Comment: can you check again my question which is `EDITED`?

Comment: this time `$live` is an object. why is that?

Comment: `$live->result[0]->meta->indicators->quote[0]->open`

Comment: this is error when try it `Undefined property: stdClass::$result`

Comment: a little bit of dumb trick here. when you see a `+` or `-` sign, then use `->` because they are public or private properties of an objects. the others are indexes of an array which you can use ['whatever_the_name_of_the_index'] to access.

Comment: `$live->chart->result[0]->indicators->quote[0]->open`

Answer (score 1):

Here `$live` is an array. Actually, it's an associative array. 'sensex' is a class.
The syntax for getting value from an associative array:

```
$var_name["key_name"];
```

For Std class, the syntax is:

```
$class_name->proparty_name
```

But we can get proparty value from Std class using associative array syntax. So.

```
$class_name["proparty_name"] is also Valid.
```

So for your case, you can use both:

```
$live["sensex"]->data->HIGH
$live["sensex"]["data"]->HIGH
$live["sensex"]["data"]["HIGH"]
```

Comment: Hello, Yes you're right here but.... I am in problem because my data really difficult.. if you can then i can paste in question.

Comment: i have added `EDITED` question.

Comment: $data->chart->result[0]->indicators->quote[0]->open
This can be the syntax. But Here I have hardcoded the index of 'result' and 'quote'.